# Toolbar Flickers while scrolling page

Tags: javascript, css, web, web-frontend

I have some problem with toolbar in my project. on some pages when I scroll the page the toolbar starts flickering.

I am using this style for toolbar class:

CSS:

```
.toolbar {
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: @bc-bg;
    height: @headerbar-height;
    color: @white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 38px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
<div class="page-container row">

    <div class="col-xs-24 page-content">

        <Top:Toolbar ID="tBar" Title='' runat="server" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltest"></asp:Label>
        <div class="row frame">
            <Top:BreadCrumb runat="server" ID="bc" />
            <div class="col-xs-24">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cplh1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cplhFoot" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: you can now see the html as well.

Comment: it's still hard to say what could be the issue.. can you replicate the bug on *[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)* or share a live link?

Comment: i meant the rendered html